# How to define custom tooltip for a column in extjs grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, tooltip, extjs-grid

How to define custom tooltip for a column in extjs grid? there is a listener for grid which apply QuickTips for whole grid but I want a column has a custom tooltip and ignore global tooltip. here the listener code on grid:

```
listeners: {
    itemmouseenter: function (view, record, item, index, e, options)
    {
        if (e.getTarget().textContent.length > 11)
           Ext.QuickTips.register({
               text: e.getTarget().textContent,
               trackMouse: true,
               target: e.target
           });
    },
}
```

I try to add this code to column,but still global one works.

Answer (score 1):

By using renderer of grid column you can show the tooltip. something like

```
var myRenderer = function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex) {
   if (colIndex === 0) {
      metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip=' + value;
   }
   // additional logic to apply to values in all columns
   return value;
}
```

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer